# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, debugging, pointers

I'm trying write a code for image segmentation in OpenCV. As a part of the image processing, I'm trying to detect the edges of a test image using Sobel filter.

In order to find the magnitude of gradient on both *dX* and *dY* direction, I'm computing the euclidean distance of both the gradients. But when I run the code I get the above error. I do know that the above error occurs when I am trying "ACCESS" an unavailable location in memory, but I am sure I have defined all `Mat` in my code.

This is part of my code.

```
//Blur the raw image to remove noise
GaussianBlur(src, src, kernel, 2);

//Run sobel edge detector
Sobel(src, edgeX, src.depth(), 1, 0);
Sobel(src, edgeY, src.depth(), 0, 1);

edge = Mat::zeros(317,554,CV_8UC1);

for (int r = 0; r < edgeX.rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < edgeY.cols; c++)
    {
        edge.at<double>(r,c) = sqrt((edgeX.at<double>(r,c)*edgeX.at<double>(r,c)) + (edgeY.at<double>(r,c)*edgeY.at<double>(r,c)));
    }
}
```

where:

- `src`: the RGB test image
- `edgeX`: sobel output with *dX* gradient
- `edgeY`: sobel output with *dY*
- `edge`: is the `Mat` with the euclidean distance.

I get the error at this line

```
edge.at<double>(r,c) = sqrt((edgeX.at<double>(r,c)*edgeX.at<double>(r,c)) + (edgeY.at<double>(r,c)*edgeY.at<double>(r,c)));
```

when trying to access `edge.at<double>(316,395)`

How do I debug this?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edge` is a matrix of type `CV_8UC1`, which means a matrix of `uchar`, not of `double`.

You need to access it with `at<uchar>`:

```
 edge.at<uchar>(r,c) = sqrt((edgeX.at<uchar>(r,c)*edgeX.at<uchar>(r,c)) + (edgeY.at<uchar>(r,c)*edgeY.at<uchar>(r,c)));
```

---

You can avoid this kind of problems using `Mat_<Tp>`, that allows also easier access without using the `.at` function:

```
Mat1b edge(317,554,uchar(0));
for (int r = 0; r < edgeX.rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < edgeY.cols; c++) {
        edge(r,c) = sqrt((edgeX(r,c)*edgeX(r,c)) + (edgeY(r,c)*edgeY(r,c)));
    }
}
```

---

In this case, you can also use [`cv::magnitude`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude) which performs the same operation you're doing with your `for` loops (but it needs matrices of `float`):

```
Sobel(src, edgeX, CV_32F, 1, 0);
Sobel(src, edgeY, CV_32F, 0, 1); 
Mat edge;
magnitude(edgeX, edgeY, edge);

// Convert to CV_8UC1
edge.convertTo(edge, CV_8UC1);
```